# Why can I create a vector of char * from char * const values?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I don't understand why vc++ and g++ let me initialize a vector< char * > from char * const values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef char *          str;
typedef char * const    cstr;

int main(int argc, const cstr argv[])
{
    const vector<str> arguments(argv + 1, argv + argc);
    for (str arg : arguments)
    {
        cout << arg << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What have you tried? What did it do? What were your expectations ?

Comment: @Ayxan That the OP doesn't expect that code to compile, at least not without a warning.

Comment: You may be confusing `const char *` with `char * const`.

Comment: Silly, sort of unrelated, question: why not just use `std::string`?

Comment: To prevent allocation of string memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pointer to a mutable char:

```
typedef char * str;
```

This is a constant pointer to a mutable char. The pointer can't change but the pointed char can be modified:

```
typedef char * const cstr;
```

There is an easy way to read pointer and const declarations: read it from right to left:

```
T * const x; // x is a constant that points to an object of type T
T const * x; // x points to a constant object of type T.
```

This argv is a pointer (a decayed array) to a constant cstr. Eventually, this is a pointer to a constant (two consts treated as one) pointer to char:

```
int main(int argc, const cstr argv[]
```

Construct a vector of str (of pointers to char), out of a collection of constant pointers to char. We don't care that the pointers themselves are constants, since the code does not modified the pointers, only copies them:

```
const vector<str> arguments(argv + 1, argv + argc)
```

No problem here.

---

Note that writing `const` on the left of the type is often called "*west const*" or, somewhat sarcastically, `const west`. In contrast, writing  `const` on the right is often called `east const`.  Semantically, `east const` and *west const* are equivalent.

The `argv` in the question uses the *west const* notation, since `const` is on the left of `cstr`. Had you used `east const` all the time, then it would have looked:

```
int main(int argc, cstr const argv[]
```

Arguably, this way of writing making it clearer that const applies to the variable `argv`, and not to the pointed value.

Comment: You might want to talk about west const vs east const

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I thought about it, but this whole go east subject sounds to be opinion based, which is against SO poilicy. Type declaration consistency is broken no matter what. For example: https://youtu.be/_27NHB1OlNI

Comment: no, I mean explain how west const may have caused the OP's confusion with the typedef.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont actually, the typedef in the question, cstr, is east const. On the other hand, argv is west const. I'll try to write something about it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have added text about east/west const